# How to place the controls of an Exoplayer outside of the PlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer2 to show videos in my application. I need the controls to be visible at all time. I can archive this by setting `app:show_timeout="0"`. But when the controls are always visible they take up space in the PlayerView.

I would like to show the controls beneath the PlayerView, so that I can always show to whole video.

This is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MediaPlayerActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:contentDescription="hf_hide_help">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:use_controller="true"
        app:rewind_increment="0"
        app:fastforward_increment="0"
        app:repeat_toggle_modes="none"
        app:show_timeout="0"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my `exo_player_control_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: Player]

And this is what it looks like, when I click on the player - the controls hide.
[image: Player without controls]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot pls?

Comment: I added the screenshots.

Comment: i have created the custom control xml file and added in PlayerView in xml file like app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls" but custom controls are displaying on PlayerView not outside of the player view. Please guide me how to display custom controls outside of PlayerView.? –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use-case is not something general and ExoPlayer doesn't support it. In your case, you will need to disable the default controls and add your own custom controls beneath the player view. It would be very easy to build the layout and add the actions to them.

**Update**: (To answer Gyan's comment about time-bar)

Two approaches: (I explain the strategies since thousands of code examples are available already on SO and other sites)

1 - My suggestion which has worked perfectly for my needs:
override default controls view of the exoplayer (having a view with the same name in your layouts folder would do the job). Then remove all unnecessary buttons which you brought down in your custom view **but** just keep the time bar in overridden view. By doing that, all the appearing / disappearing behaviors are automatically kept for the time bar and you will have the rest in your own view. You wouldn't need to worry about handling the time bar if you liked that approach.

2- Just in case you insist on bringing the time bar out under the player window, what you need is a horizontal progressbar (Notice that you can customize the look of progress view to match your design). Then write a listener on exoplayer to take the timings (passed / remaining / current play-time) and calculate and update the progress of the bar based upon them. Remember that the progress bar needs to be touchable (and focusable) so that the user could drag it back and forth. Then you would need to re-calculate playtime when user drags the progress. (lots of coding and calculations obviously but almost easy stuff). Hope it works for you. If you needed code samples please let me know.

Comment: i have created the custom control xml file and added in PlayerView in xml file like app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls"  but custom controls are displaying on PlayerView not outside of the player view. Please guide me how to display custom controls outside of PlayerView.?

Comment: If you add it like that using app:controller_layout_id, the behavior would be exactly like the original controls of exoplayer. Just put your own controllers in another view and stick it below the player view. (for example you could have a vertical linearlayout which has the player as first child and the controls view as the second child). hope you got it

Comment: yes i created Linearlayout (orientation=vertical) and  playerview is inside it , now i added second child as frame layout and inside frame laout i used <include layout="@layout/custom_controls"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />   =====> and i removed app:controller_layout_id, from playerview , now custom controls are visible below playerview but all controls are dead, Not in working stage just like dead UI.

Comment: Sure it is a dead UI unless you add some code to your buttons to take actions. for example your custom play button would run this snippet: 
exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
and pause needs to run:
exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false . You gotta be able to figure out the rest I believe

Comment: Thanks @Masoud Dadashi  thank you so much, now play and pause is working , but if i use com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar  for showing the progress any solution for this just like play and pause ? how to manage DefaultTimeBar progress ?

Comment: I edit my answer since the explanation requires more space than comment length

Answer (score 0):

Here I have play/pause button on the video and other controls under the video, here is how to do it.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:auto_show="true"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_overlay_controller_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/exoBottomControls"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:repeat_toggle_modes="none"
            app:resize_mode="fixed_width"
            app:surface_type="surface_view"
            app:use_controller="true" />
    
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerControlView
            android:id="@+id/exoBottomControls"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_exo_bottom_controller_view"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/video_view"
            app:show_timeout="0" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here i am using both use_controller=true and StyledPlayerControlView.

controls which should appear on the video should go in your custom_exo_overlay_controller_view other views which should appear under the video should go in custom_exo_bottom_controller_view.

here is custom_exo_overlay_controller_view.xml

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play_pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and custom_exo_bottom_controller_view.xml

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <View
            android:id="@id/exo_controls_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/color_secondary_black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="00:50" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:text="02:50" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exo_sound_on"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sound_on"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exo_duration"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/exo_sound_off"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sound_off"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exo_duration"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
    
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            app:buffered_color="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:played_color="@android:color/transparent"
            app:scrubber_drawable="@drawable/ic_scrubber"
            app:touch_target_height="52dp"
            app:unplayed_color="@android:color/transparent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

also you should assign your controller like this

```
        player = ExoPlayer.Builder(binding.root.context).build().also {
            binding.videoView.player = it
            binding.exoBottomControls.player = it
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(video.url)
            it.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            it.seekTo(video.currentWindow, video.playbackPosition)
            it.prepare()
        }
```

Comment: What is the replacement for other control such as `exo_prev` or `exo_rew`? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How can I hide the view control automatically?

Comment: @eliassharafi if i remember correctly, `app:auto_show="true"` in `StyledPlayerView` xml tag should get the job done. also `show_timeout` in `StyledPlayerControlView` tag should have value other than 0