# Using exoplayer in Android

Tags: android, exoplayer

I've been able to add the exoplayer to my android application. Is there a way to show the controls on default. You have the hover over the play button for people to see it now. Here's my activity code

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_controller"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/author"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.787" />
```

custom_playback_controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    android:background="#CC000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_prev"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_rew"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_shuffle"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Shuffle"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_repeat_toggle"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_play"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_pause"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_ffwd"
            android:tint="#FF00A6FF"
            style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@id/exo_next"
        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FF00A6FF"/>

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="26dp"/>

        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:textColor="#FF00A6FF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: One similar question: [How to place the controls of an Exoplayer outside of the PlayerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51856565/how-to-place-the-controls-of-an-exoplayer-outside-of-the-playerview) (it's not an exact duplicate, therefore I refrained from closing the question); tag `kotlin` removed, as there is no code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can either do :

```xml
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:use_controller="true"/>
```

or [programmatically](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setUseController-boolean) and [setControllerShowTimeoutMs](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#setControllerShowTimeoutMs-int-):

```java
exoplayer.setUseController(true);
exoplayer.setControllerShowTimeoutMs(0);
```

Comment: It works now but it doesn't show the player by default. What should I do?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerView.html#isControllerVisible--) you have 2 methods you can use to always show control which are `isControllerVisible` and `showController`.